# Website Systematically Blocking IP Addresses

Tags: web-hosting, security

I have a series of websites hosted at the same server. The issue I am having is that it keeps blocking me access from different means to the sites. Allow me to explain:

- From my IP, Blocked.
- From Boomproxy: Blocked
- From Zend2: Blocked
- From hidemyass: Blocked
- From Zacebook: Accessible

**The "Block" message goes something like this:**

> Exact error is: This webpage is not available The connection to
>   www.xxx.yyy was interrupted. Here are some suggestions: Reload this
>   webpage later. Check your Internet connection.
>
> Restart any router, modem, or... etc, etc ...Go to the Chrome menu >
>   Settings > Show advanced settings... > Change proxy settings... > LAN
>   Settings and deselect the "Use a proxy server for your LAN" checkbox.
>   Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.

Please remember that no matter what proxy service I use, it systematically "blocks" them one by one.

Does anybody know how this keeps happening? It also affects any access to the sites from my network.

Comment: I'm assuming this happens for any attempt at access, including static files?

Comment: Yes, for everything.

Comment: Here is an update:
The webmaster whitelisted our IP but we are still not able to access the sites and the error message changed to:
The webpage at `http://xxx.yyy.zzz/` might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED): Unknown error
Any new ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, you have been most helpful in solving this.

Finally, the Hosting Provider came out and notified that they noticed the websites were being accessed from another country and they thought their clients were going to move the sites away from them. Therefore, they shut access to the countries they were being accessed from.

Stupid, I agree.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access your site only from some ips, check your .htaccess file first of all.In case there are the following lines there:

deny from all
allow from 126.90.90.9

this means that the access to the site is blocked from all the ips and only allowed from 126.90.90.9.

The second thing which can ifluence the site performance can be connected with mod_security module installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

**Contact your Web Host Provider**

Your website will not be banning you and it's actually a security protocol at your hosting. If it is shared hosting you need to contact them regarding them blocking you. Many shared web hosts have tight security measures and I've seen some even ban if you have too many server-side requests (Such as FTP uploading of files). Simply bouncing from one proxy, browser, or vpn is not going to resolve any issue until you address the real issue of your web host blocking you from their system.

Contact your web hosting or administrator and have them disable fail2ban or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more information eg: which web server you're using, do you use CMS etc. It is hard to provide a solution to your problem. It could caused by a security plugin in your CMS or a module in your web server. For example, your host could have setup Nginx to return 444 (drop connection) when it detects no referral in the http header.